# Set initial data in Django Form forms.Select()

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to set initial value for my staus field that is forms.Select() widget in django ModelForm but it does not work. I cant debug my code.

My model form class is:

```
class CRMFollowUpStatusLogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CRMFollowUpStatusLog
        fields = ['status']
        widgets = {
            "status": forms.Select()
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        status_id = kwargs["data"]["followup"].current_status.id
        # status_id is correctly passed here
        self.fields['status'].initial = status_id
```

status_id is correctly passed to init method. but self.fields['status'].initial = status_id does not work correctly.

CRMFollowUpStatusLog is:

```
class CRMFollowUpStatusLog(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(
        "CRMFollowUpStatus", related_name="follow_up_logs", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    follow_up = models.ForeignKey(
        "CRMFollowUp", related_name="status_logs", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

and CRMFollowUpStatus is:

```
class CRMFollowUpStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
```

status_id in **init** method of CRMFollowUpStatusLogForm is pk of CRMFollowUpStatus.